# IntelliJ IDEA don't see project gradle modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have imported Gradle project into IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3 Community Edition.
The project consist of 2 internal and 4 external gradle modules. Here is root `settings.gradle` file

```
include ':main', ':framework_test', ':framework', ':data', ':domain', ':util'
project(':data').projectDir = new File('../common/data')
project(':domain').projectDir = new File('../common/domain')
project(':framework').projectDir = new File('../common/framework')
project(':util').projectDir = new File('../common/util')
```

On the 'Gradle projects' pane I see all the modules are imported

[image: 'Gradle projects' pane]

But on the 'Project' pane there are only internal modules

[image]

Pressing 'Synchronize' and 'Refresh all Gradle projects' buttons does not help.

**Though** running `gradlew build` from command line I see, that gladle builds all the 6 modules.
But I cant't build or run project from IDE. Moreover, when I try to create run configuration, IDE can't find any of project classes.

WTF with this IDE??

Comment: Have you tried to import them as modules: `File` -> `New...` -> `Module from existing source`?

Comment: Well, have tried now to import ':data' from '../common/data'. After pressing OK in 'Import Module from Gradle' window error window 'Cannot Save Settings' appears with message 'The project is already registered'.

Comment: What solved me was to `clone` the repository the project was in and re-open it. An additional problem was that I also could not start a specific project because the main class could not be found. Strange.

Edit: cloning means the `workspace.xml` and a couple other xml files inside the `idea` folder have been regenerated.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this after import by going to File -> Invalidate caches/restart

After restarting the module appeared in the navigator

Comment: Came across a similar issue to the OP, but trying to import a Gradle module that leveraged a Kotlin DSL. Other Gradle modules using the Groovy DSL imported without issue. I tried removing all project references in the .idea folder, but the import still failed. Using this approach to invalidate cache + restart also worked for me.